# How do you make the unit test sleep for a period of time within the database pro version of visual studio?

Tags: sql, tdd, visual-studio-dbpro

using visual studio (database pro) 2008, i have created a unit test (using the SQL unit test) that tests several stored procedures in order.

The solution is designed to call each SP after a period of time, not within the same second.

Thus the unit test fail and requires a short pause between each call.

Any ideas? is there a standard `Thread.Sleep` style function i can use?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but, try to fix the SPs and not try to force the tests to give the results you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having unit tests that are slow is always bad. Having unit tests depending on each other (don't know if that is the case) is also bad.

So I strongly suggest you try designing your code so you can test without the delays. But if you really want delays [WaitFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331(SQL.90).aspx) might be the solution (assuming SQL server).